# Couple of questions about python

Tags: python

i'm currently a computer engineering student and i have a couple of quick questions pertaining to a homework i'm not quite sure i understand.

The first one is "is python a proprietary language" I'm not sure if that's translated correctly so apologies in advance

The secon one is "is python free software" technicaly it's a programming language right? Does it count as software?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: For your second question: Python is a language not a software, an implementation of Python like an interpreter is a software. There are many, they can have different licenses. The most common like CPython and Pypy are free software.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python is free software, and it's open source. Anyone can use it in a commercial or public project.

Python is not a proprietary language, for the same reasons.

Source: https://docs.python.org/3/license.html

Comment: No, Python is a _programming language_. The software is the interpreter.

Comment: What's the difference between a programming language and software?

Comment: It is basically the same as the difference between English and a person speaking English.

Comment: In that analogy speaking English would be running the software as an act, not the software itself

Comment: A language is a set of rules and constraints that describe syntax and semantics. A interpreter is a software that reads a text file and tries to follow its contents based on a specific language.

Comment: Python is "free software" in the sense that anyone can see its specification and implement interpreters for the language, or even implement with modifications.

Comment: Ok that makes sense to me. I guess @Gabriel like all software is a subset of languages (since software has to inherit the rules and constraints of some language) but are some languages not software? This is beyond the scope of the original question, I guess

Comment: "all software is a subset of languages" all software is written in some language, yes. However I'm not talking about the language in which the interpreter was _written_, I'm talking about the language the interpreter _reads_.

Comment: Sure @Gabriel I just saw a bunch of folks saying that programming languages are not software and I'm trying to wrap my head around what the difference is.

Comment: A language is a specification, a concept, an idea. It usually defines an alphabet (the characters of the language), rules to combine these characters (build sentences) etc. This applies to any written language (Python, English, Latin...). Note that languages change over time (the English we speak today is not equal to the English spoken 500 years ago, and the Python we write today is not equal to the Python writen 15 years ago). Languages change over time because, as I said, they're ideas, and ideas change. [cont]

Comment: The purpose of a language is always to express thoughts. I'm using English to express my thoughts right now. Some languages have some more specific purpose, and it's the case of programming languages: They're designed to express flows of logical thinking in order to be eventually converted into machine code.
Each programming language is designed to express specific kinds of logical thinking. Matlab is very good for thoughts related to mathematics, Prolog is very good for thoughts related to logic, VHDL is very good for thoughts related to integrated circuits. [cont]

Comment: I hope you now can see that languages (both programming languages or otherwise) are purely concepts, not a "software". [end]

Comment: @Gabriel I can see A) how they're conceptual, and I can see B) how all software is a subset of programming languages, but not how to infer from A+B that programming languages are not software. At any rate you've been exceedingly generous explaining A & B to me and I'll spend some time wrapping my head around C on my own. Thank you!